# Is "what we're going to do is + verb" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=9)

> What we're going to do `is translate` the understanding about gradients that we saw in the previous video into ...

What we are taught at school is "be + to + verb" or "be + verb + ing".

It seems that "be + verb" is NOT grammatical.

Although, I heard a lot people say "what we're going to do is + verb", even college professors. So, in particular, is "what we're going to do is + verb" grammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly grammatical, and even common. The forms you have been taught are the most common forms, but they are not the only forms that can be grammatical.

Comment: And "what we're going to do is `to` translate ..." is also grammatical, right?

Comment: @fu Yes, it is.